# Can I play Minecraft JE on a mobile phone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I currently don't have a computer or laptop (anymore). I do have an iPad and a tablet, and I do have a Minecraft: Java Edition account, but I can't use it, and Minecraft PE is just not the same.
Is there any way to play Minecraft JE on any of my mobile devices?

Comment: What kind of tablet?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid not. Minecraft PE is the only edition you are able to play on mobile devices.

Comment: That is not necessarily true, if you had a tablet with full Windows (Not RT) then you could run Minecraft. It would very likely run terribly...but you could play it.

Comment: @JostySpoons that's not technically "mobile" in the sense of it being a *mobile OS*, such as iOS or Android for which PE (now Bedrock) can be played on.  A tablet running Windows is essentially a laptop, but in a tablet form factor.

Answer (score 2):

there was something in Google Play called Boardwalk I think that lets you play minecraft pc on android but of course

You will have to be ready to play at 5fps

Comment: I actually got 30 FPS with it once, but I don't think it works for Minecraft 1.13 and above.

Answer (score 2):

Your only bet on how to play PC version is if you had a PC running the game, and a streaming software such as splashtops or team viewer. Getting it to work smoothly is the problem though, as input methods can be limited. So in theory you could via streaming, but to play it directly on your tablet would be impossible right now unless someone can make a jar or exe emulator for android/apple devices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if you use boardwalk but you can no longer download ot with playstore, you must usw a website download link.

Comment: Is it legal? Can you provide a link?

Comment: I am not sure if it is legal or not but you could go to https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.apkpure.com/boardwalk/net.zhuoweizhang.boardwalk&ved=2ahUKEwiBg6b3oqXjAhVXB50JHT5PDSgQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3S0nXIW-t9-XKtbzrz3iQx (feel free to copy link)

Answer (score -1):

You can use cloud gaming services such as Shadow, Netboom and *not Vortex*